# Is it okay to ask question about certain parts of the gaming industry?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I know that there's an SE site for Game Development so I know those questions are right out. However, what about questions that are related to the industry but aren't covered by Game Development, such as game journalism and other 'meta' topics?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to ask? In general, we don't do questions that are fundamentally speculative or purely opinionated in nature, and I can't really think of any useful (read, not general reference) questions like what you're describing that don't fall into those categories. Some examples would help.

Comment: Yep, actually giving us at least the question title would be a great way to see if your own question would be okay or not.

Comment: Or, just go ahead and ask the question.  Having your question closed isn't a big deal, there's no penalty for it, and it gives people something concrete to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

It's not explicitly defined in the current FAQ, but **indirectly, such questions are outlined as unacceptable because they are typically more about discussion, have a high degree of subjectivity and and lack concrete answers to solve an explicit problem. ***

**As long as your question fits within the guides as defined in the FAQ, then your question on any of the non-prohibited subjects should be perfectly fine.**

Currently the FAQ says:

> You should only ask `practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face`. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

and

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

The FAQ only specific prohibits questions about:

> - Game and Mod Development (try the Game Development Stack Exchange instead)
> - Requests for game identification
> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)
> - Shopping advice and recommendations
> - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases
> - Piracy, and support with pirated games.